# JavaScript not responsive before PHP (form action = "php file" onsubmit= " form’s fields validating function"

Tags: javascript

I have investigated for a long time (too long) on the net (including StackOverflow e.g.) without any success. The question is asked by many people but no one among the proposed solutions helps me. So in desperation, I turn again to this forum.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="updateMySQLGuests.php" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
```

This boolean result function checks whether the value of the fields is correct before calling `UpdateMySQLGuests.php` (for example, verify if the e-mail contains a `@`) to create a record with the value of these form fields by POST method in MySQL. But `action= updateMySQLGuests.php` is executed before the `formSubmit()` function (which, in fact, is not executed at all). I work in `localhost` with Wampserver.

Comment: Could you share the complete HTML form for investigation?

Comment: There's no php here or mysql that you mentioned in your post. There's only HTML here and no JS.

Comment: post related js code as well

Answer (score 0):

You can move the form's action to `formSubmit()` to solve this

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
```

and the `formSubmit()` code:

```
function formSubmit() {
  // the old code
  ...

  // call submit form
  document.getElementById('myForm').action = "updateMySQLGuests.php";
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--  in place of <form name= "myForm" id="myForm" action="updateMySQLGuests.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formSubmit()"> : -->

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="updateMySQLGuests.php" method="post">
    <!-- action="updateMySQLGuests.php" -->
    <label for="firstnames">Prénom:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" size="20" name="firstname"><br>
    <label for="Lastnames">Nom:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" size="20" name="lastname" list="lstLastnames">
    <datalist id="lstLastnames"> </datalist> <br>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" size="20" name="email"><br><br>

    <!-- in place of <input type="submit" value="post"/> : -->

    <button onclick="return validateValues()">Submit</button>
</form>
```